# Pyspark df.count() Why does it work with only one executor?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to read data from kafka and I want to get the count of it.
It takes a long time because it works with only one executor. how can i increase it?

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('oracle_read_test') \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "30g") \
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "64g") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "10") \
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "15") \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '30g') \
    .config('num-executors', '20') \
    .config('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', '32g') \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("orc.compress", "ZLIB") \
    .config("hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize", "40000000") \
    .config("hive.merge.size.per.task", "209715200") \
    .config("dfs.blocksize", "268435456") \
    .config("hive.metastore.try.direct.sql", "true") \
    .config("spark.sql.orc.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false") \
    .config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092") \
     .option("includeHeaders","true") \
     .option("subscribe","test") \
     .load()

df.count()
```

[image: yarn interface]

Answer (score 0):

How many partitions does your topic have? If only one, then you cannot have more executors.

Otherwise, `--num-executors` exists as a flag to `spark-submit`.

Also, this code only counts the records returned in one batch, not the entire topic. Counting the entire topic would take even longer.

Comment: topic has 3 partitions.I gave the num-executor parameter It runs with 1 executor when doing where and then show to the dataframe..

Comment: Are you using something other than `--master=local`? I've read that local master will only ever use one executor

Comment: I am using it as --master yarn.

Comment: You are only using one machine, then? Or are all the YARN nodemanagers also running a Kafka broker? Otherwise, `localhost:9092` won't really work

Comment: When I try to read from csv, executors are running as many as cores but when i read from kafka only single executor work. is single executor run specific to kafka? I added the session properties I created above...

Comment: As mentioned, it should start one executor per partition. You may need to enable dynamic allocation, but also, you shouldn't need 30g for the driver, and 30g for 15 executors (when the max you can have is 6) is excessive, IMO (num-executors config isn't doing anything)